# problem with adafruit-blinka

Tags: adafruit, circuitpython

I tried to install python3.7 and made it the default python version.
Now I'm trying to install this:

```
pip3 install adafruit-blinka
```

and I get this error

```
Collecting adafruit-blinka
Collecting rpi-ws281x>=4.0.0 (from adafruit-blinka)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/d4/75fcc4f3412b9b16e39e6cd6156f2e171fe7b2e79057be17d1acf38fded4/rpi_ws281x-4.3.4.tar.gz
Collecting Adafruit-PlatformDetect>=3.13.0 (from adafruit-blinka)
Collecting pyftdi>=0.40.0 (from adafruit-blinka)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/ce/a97811c3e7e2d5a9520b88801dcc70ac1b553ed31b9819b2fce14ffa9aa3/pyftdi-0.54.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting RPi.GPIO (from adafruit-blinka)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/0f/10b524a12b3445af1c607c27b2f5ed122ef55756e29942900e5c950735f2/RPi.GPIO-0.7.1.tar.gz
Collecting Adafruit-PureIO>=1.1.7 (from adafruit-blinka)
Collecting adafruit-circuitpython-typing (from adafruit-blinka)
Collecting sysv-ipc>=1.1.0 (from adafruit-blinka)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/d7/5d2f861155e9749f981e6c58f2a482d3ab458bf8c35ae24d4b4d5899ebf9/sysv_ipc-1.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting pyserial>=3.0 (from pyftdi>=0.40.0->adafruit-blinka)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/bc/587a445451b253b285629263eb51c2d8e9bcea4fc97826266d186f96f558/pyserial-3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyusb!=1.2.0,>=1.0.0 (from pyftdi>=0.40.0->adafruit-blinka)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/a8/4982498b2ab44d1fcd5c49f07ea3795eab01601dc143b009d333fcace3b9/pyusb-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting adafruit-circuitpython-busdevice (from adafruit-circuitpython-typing->adafruit-blinka)
Collecting typing-extensions; python_version <= "3.7" (from adafruit-circuitpython-typing->adafruit-blinka)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/e1/932e06004039dd670c9d5e1df0cd606bf46e29a28e65d5bb28e894ea29c9/typing_extensions-4.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: rpi-ws281x, RPi.GPIO, sysv-ipc
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for rpi-ws281x ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4ezv0p7d/rpi-ws281x/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpxb_0fx99pip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  Compiling ws281x library...
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/rpi_ws281x
  copying rpi_ws281x/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/rpi_ws281x
  copying rpi_ws281x/rpi_ws281x.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/rpi_ws281x
  running build_ext
  building '_rpi_ws281x' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/dma.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/dma.o
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/mailbox.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/mailbox.o
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/main.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/main.o
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/pcm.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/pcm.o
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/pwm.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/pwm.o
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/rpihw.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/rpihw.o
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/ws2811.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/ws2811.o
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c rpi_ws281x_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/rpi_ws281x_wrap.o
  rpi_ws281x_wrap.c:130:11: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   # include <Python.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for rpi-ws281x
  Running setup.py clean for rpi-ws281x
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for RPi.GPIO ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4ezv0p7d/RPi.GPIO/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpcwgw18j8pip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/RPi
  copying RPi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/RPi
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/RPi/GPIO
  copying RPi/GPIO/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/RPi/GPIO
  running build_ext
  building 'RPi._GPIO' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/source
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c source/c_gpio.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/source/c_gpio.o
  source/c_gpio.c: In function ‘setup’:
  source/c_gpio.c:170:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
       if ((uint32_t)gpio_mem % PAGE_SIZE)
           ^
  source/c_gpio.c:171:34: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
           gpio_mem += PAGE_SIZE - ((uint32_t)gpio_mem % PAGE_SIZE);
                                    ^
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c source/common.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/source/common.o
  source/common.c:23:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include "Python.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for RPi.GPIO
  Running setup.py clean for RPi.GPIO
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for sysv-ipc ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4ezv0p7d/sysv-ipc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp4e5nly5kpip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  ******************************************************************************
  * Setup can't determine the value of PAGE_SIZE on your system, so it will
  * default to 4096 which may not be correct.
  *
  * Please report this message and your operating system info to the package
  * maintainer listed in the README file.
  ******************************************************************************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'sysv_ipc' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c common.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/common.o
  common.c:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include "Python.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for sysv-ipc
  Running setup.py clean for sysv-ipc
Failed to build rpi-ws281x RPi.GPIO sysv-ipc
Installing collected packages: rpi-ws281x, Adafruit-PlatformDetect, pyserial, pyusb, pyftdi, RPi.GPIO, Adafruit-PureIO, adafruit-circuitpython-busdevice, typing-extensions, adafruit-circuitpython-typing, sysv-ipc, adafruit-blinka
  Running setup.py install for rpi-ws281x ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4ezv0p7d/rpi-ws281x/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-t1v32mvf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
    running build
    running build_py
    Compiling ws281x library...
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/rpi_ws281x
    copying rpi_ws281x/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/rpi_ws281x
    copying rpi_ws281x/rpi_ws281x.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/rpi_ws281x
    running build_ext
    building '_rpi_ws281x' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/dma.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/dma.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/mailbox.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/mailbox.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/main.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/main.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/pcm.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/pcm.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/pwm.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/pwm.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/rpihw.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/rpihw.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c lib/ws2811.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/lib/ws2811.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c rpi_ws281x_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-37/rpi_ws281x_wrap.o
    rpi_ws281x_wrap.c:130:11: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     # include <Python.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4ezv0p7d/rpi-ws281x/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-t1v32mvf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4ezv0p7d/rpi-ws281x/
```

How can fix it?

Comment: Is this Bullseye or Buster?  I have it working on Buster with 3.7. in a pipenv environment.  But, I gave up on Bullseye, that was a few months back but from memory it was GPIO that I had issues with in blinka

Answer (score 0):

At a guess you are missing some of the needed development files.

Try

`sudo apt install python3-dev python3-setuptools`

or possibly

`sudo apt install python-dev python-setuptools`

Then try building again.

Comment: How to build again?

Comment: `pip3 install adafruit-blinka` should try to build.

Comment: No, didn't work. I tried it. The problem remain

Comment: I suppose there is no build environment available for Python 3.7.  It sounds like you are on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

```
# Check python2.x version
python --version
# Check python3.x version
python3 --version
sudo apt-get install python-dev   # for python2.x installs
sudo apt-get install python3-dev  # for python3.x installs
pip3 install adafruit-blinka
```